# Disable or remove Category view on product overview

Tags: magento2

Is there a easy way to remove or disable the category view on a product overview page ? I like to keep the filter view below the category view

http://prntscr.com/m83gmm

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a file in app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and add :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
          <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
     </body>
</page>
```